# div element has a margin

Tags: css, html, margin

I have built a content div with three further divs who have the

> display:inline-block;

attribute. One of them contains another div element which has some audio controlls. The right div has a really big margin! Chrome and Firefox don't show any margins or paddings. If I delete the #music element, everything is okay.

[Here is a live demo](http://wernersbacher.de/music/)

Thanks for helping

Comment: Try showing relevant code with the stack snippet.

Comment: Have you tried using `display:block;` with `float:left`?

Comment: Put some content in other divs and see the difference. It's `vertical-align` of `inline-block`s. Anyway, why not use flex-boxes?

Comment: Inline block items have a default alignment of `baseline`. You need to use `vertical-align:top`.

Comment: @AlexeyTen I am discovering flex boxes now. They are amazing. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using the `display: inline-block;` definition, your content is verticaly aligned to `baseline` by default.

Apply this on your .frames class:

```
vertical-align: top;
```

Problem solved. ;)

Comment: To baseline, actually. But baseline of inline block is complex and non-obvious thing quite hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

if you add `float:left` to `#music` it gets fixed _

---

as suggested using clearfix on parent element doesn't hurt:

```
.parent:after{
  display:table;
  content: "",
  clear:both
 }
```

Comment: dont forget to mention: in this case he should use clearfix ;)